# how to set border color for more than one uitextfield on begin editing in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 uitextfields and i have also written the code for setting the border color for uitextfield on begin editing , but when i click on one uitextfield all the other two textfields border also turns to orange.

Need some help

```
var colorBorder = UIColor(netHex:0xdb8925)
self.uitextfieldAmount.delegate = self
self.uitextfieldBeneficiaryID.delegate = self
self.uitextfieldNote.delegate = self

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    uitextfieldBeneficiaryID.layer.borderColor = colorBorder.CGColor
    //uitextfieldAmount.layer.borderColor = colorBorder.CGColor
    //uitextfieldNote.layer.borderColor = colorBorder.CGColor
}
```

Comment: then use condition.

Comment: simply use   `func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.layer.borderColor = colorBorder.CGColor  }`

Comment: thanx for your time @Anbu.Karthik , i am a newbie in swift ios , it would be great if a person like you would guide me in improving my swift skills.

Comment: not like that bro, i am not a genious compare to google, at the same everyone does not know everything, day by day pratice its automatically improve ourself , so dont feel at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
var colorBorder = UIColor(netHex:0xdb8925)
self.uitextfieldAmount.delegate = self
self.uitextfieldBeneficiaryID.delegate = self
self.uitextfieldNote.delegate = self

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == uitextfieldBeneficiaryID {
        uitextfieldBeneficiaryID.layer.borderColor = // Color you want
    } else if textField == uitextfieldAmount {
        uitextfieldAmount.layer.borderColor = // Color you want
    } else {
        uitextfieldNote.layer.borderColor = // Color you want
    }
}
```

Try like this. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both these delegate methods if you want to highlight the currently editing text field. 
Please make sure that you have properly set the delegate to each text fields.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change as below :

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.layer.borderColor = colorBorder.CGColor
  }
```

Comment: Thanx for your time @KKRocks